# inputのvalueはどのように格納されている？

Tags: javascript, html5

下記のコード（完結しているためbodyの中身のみ抽出）を実行すると、inputの中身とそのvalueがコンソール画面に表示されますが、両者のvalueが合いません。具体的には先に出力される方のvalueは初期値のままで、後の方は変更後のvalueになります。

通常、valueの取得では

```
.value
```

を付けるので問題ありませんが、当然range自体も変わると思っていました。そこで、以下2点の疑問が生じ、調べてはみましたがそれに関する詳細を見つけられませんでした。

#### 疑問

- rangeに表示される値はrange.valueとは異なる格納方法のようだが、rangeのどこに格納されているのか
- そもそもrangeやrange.valueはどのような構造（？）で格納されているのか

以上、ご回答お願いします。

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="100" id="range" />
<script>
  (function() {
    var range = document.getElementById("range");
    range.addEventListener("change",  function() {
      console.log(range);
      console.log(range.value);
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

inputの　**value Attribute（value=）**  はコントロールの初期値です。

type="range"の時 range.valueは、 **表示されているslider control**  の値です。

`<input>:` 入力欄（フォーム入力）要素（https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-value）では、
value コントロールの初期値です。この属性は type 属性の値が radio または checkbox である場合を除き、省略可能です。
 ページを再読み込みするとき、Gecko および IE は再読み込み前に値が変更された場合に HTML ソースで指定された値を無視する 点に注意してください。

HTML DOM Input Range Object（https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_range.asp）では、
value　 Sets or returns the value of the value attribute of a slider control

と書いてあります。